# CONT.SES ENTRE ARQUIVOS DIFERENTES LIBREOFFICE/EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou utilizando o `CONT.SES` entre **arquivos diferentes**, mas estou recebendo:

> ERRO:504.

A fórmula está assim:

```
=CONT.SES('file:///C:/Users/jaciel.barros/Desktop/RELATÓRIOS/JANEIRO2016.ods'#$JANEIRO.$O$3:$O$75;"SIM";'file:///C:/Users/jaciel.barros/Desktop/RELATÓRIOS/JANEIRO2016.ods'#$JANEIRO.$L$3:$L$75;"GURGEL")
```

Comment: Oi Jaciel. Essa é uma nova tentativa, ou você tinha essa fórmula já funcionando alguma vez? Eu nunca vi usar um caminho com nome de arquivo numa fórmula, e por isso tenho minhas dúvidas se isso funciona. Mas estou curioso pra saber. Vc levou algumas negativações e votos para fechar, talvez por ter sido muito direto ou por ter dado poucos detalhes.

Comment: Que tal editar a pergunta para incluir informações a respeito da fonte de onde vc tirou que isso é possível, ou descrevendo exatamente o que vc precisa fazer? Talvez a pergunta fique melhor se for somente: "é possível executar fórmula com dados de outro arquivo?"

Comment: P.S.: Tá, a pergunta pode ser melhorada, mas eu não acho ela mereça ser fechada ou ganhar negativações. Quem votou assim poderia explicar o motivo, até para ajudar o Jaciel a melhorar o conteúdo?

Comment: Me parece ser algum bug na função `CONT.SES`, porque eu fiz com a `CONT.SE` e funcionou normalmente, você poderia tentar concatenar os dados das colunas O e L, separando com um traço, e depois usar o `CONT.SE` informando como critério a informação concatenada, tipo "SIM-GURGEL".

Answer (score 0):

**Erro 504** => **Erro na lista de parâmetros** => Um parâmetro da função não é válido, por exemplo, um texto em vez de um número ou uma referência de domínio em vez de uma referência de célula.